# Handle exception in PHP

Tags: php, exception, web, error-handling, url-routing

Looking for a little help, I have a basic php index page set up on wamp.

Access able by navigating to localhost/test/ in a browser.

However when navigating to the url if I append a "'" it returns the version of apache being used and the port used for communication, which may be dangerous in the wrong hands.

Can you tell me is there a quick way to handle any unresolved urls in php to return a message of say "Incorrect URL entered"?

Im very new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code is:

```
<?php include "config.php"; ?>
```

I have tried googling but being unfamiliar with the terminology is making this near impossible.

Thank you Wayne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two (main) ways to do this:

## Option 1 - Route all traffic to a particular page

First, you can route all traffic to one page and handle errors therein. You do this by adding a general `RewriteRule` to your `.htaccess` file. Example:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Your `index.php` then has to handle both legitimate and incorrect URLs.

## Option 2 - Use a custom error handler page

Create a document to handle 404s. Example:

```
<?php
echo "Sorry, that page wasn't found";
```

Set that document as the 404 handler in `.htaccess` with this rule:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
```

(Where 404.php is whatever you named the document you just created.)

Option 2 is easier, but Option 1 is often desirable in more complex applications.

Comment: Hi Ed, Thank you for the reply, would you know of any step by step guides for option 2? As I am very new to this the terms our over my head.

Comment: @WayneBowden I tried to explain it already. Is there a step that isn't clear? You just need to create a page, such as 404.php, that will handle your 404 errors, and add the line `ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php` to your `.htaccess` file. If that isn't clear, please let me know which part doesn't make sense.

Comment: Okay thank you, Just a few clarifying questions,  Is the .htaccess file something I need to create in the folder with the other webpages or is this something to be changed in the wamp directory?

Comment: @WayneBowden in the same directory as the other pages.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you, and is this something I have to add for all errors? IS there a way for the message "Sorry, that page wasn't found" to be output regardless of error?

Comment: @WayneBowden what do you mean? That's probably not how you want to handle errors that aren't 404 errors. You can handle others on a case-by-case basis with, for example, `ErrorDocument 500 some-error-handler-file.php`.

Comment: Hi Ed,

So I created the files and input the above code mentioned, but still getting the same error with all server details and port showing, am I missing something?

Comment: @WayneBowden Yes, you're missing something. Make sure to replace the `/errors/404.php` in the example rule with the path to and name of the file you created. And make sure you named your `.htaccess` file exactly that - `.htaccess` - and not something else, like `index.htaccess`.

Comment: Okay, thank you

So I have validated, the file is named ".htaccess" and located with the rest of the web pages in directory c:/wamp/www/test1

The ".htaccess" file contains the code "ErrorDocument 404 /localhost/test1/404.php"

The file 404.php is located in the same directory and contains the following code "<?php
echo "Sorry, that page wasn't found";"

Am I missing some code or pointing to the incorrect directory?

Just a side note the ".htaccess" file is showing as a php file type is that correct?

Comment: Change `ErrorDocument 404 /localhost/test1/404.php` to `ErrorDocument 404 404.php`. The filename needs to be relative to your website, not relative to your filesystem. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by `the ".htaccess" file is showing as a php file type` but no, that's not correct. You need to double-check that the file name is `.htaccess`, not something like `.htaccess.php`.

Comment: You sure are a legend, its now working, thank you so much!

Comment: @WayneBowden Glad to help! Please remember to select an answer (click the check mark)! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your different pages into files then setting up a "router" which checks the desired URL and renders the appropriate page. Something like this:

```
// index.php

function goToURL ($url) {
    // render the page at $url
    include ($url);
}

$routed = false;
$url = $_SERVER ['SCRIPT_URL'];
$routes = array (
    '/foo' => 'SomePage.php',
    '/bar' => 'OtherPage.php'
);

foreach ($routes as $k => $v) {
    if (strpos ($url, $k) !== false) {
        goToURL ($v);
        $routed = true;
    }
}

// if no specific url matches then just send them to the home page
if (!$routed) {
    goToURL ('Home.php');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response,

Should I just be adding this code to the index.php file I included all code from above?

Comment: The code from your original post should probably be put into something like `Main.php` or `Login.php` or something. The code from my post is meant to go into `index.php` because that's what the web server will server by default. Your URLs would look like `mysite.com/index.php/foo`. This is similar to the way that CodeIgniter and other PHP frameworks function; though my example is much more simplistic.